# Ubuntu 20.04 only detecting one out of three monitors with RX 7900XT

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, multiple-monitors

I recently built a new PC with three monitors and installed Windows, which worked without any issues. I then tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22 in dualboot on a separate drive, but unfortunately, I only have one monitor working on Ubuntu, unlike Windows.
My GPU is an RX 7900XT.
When I run the xrandr command, I get the error message "Failed to get size of gamma for output default"

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen 0:
minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080 default
connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
    1920x1080     77.00*
```

and the output indicates that only one monitor is connected. I need help to resolve this issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Great to that you were able to resolve your issue. This will help others in the future with similar issues. When able, please be sure to set this question to answered (accept your answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

The problem was nomodeset
I saw it when I ran the `amdgpu-install command`, it told me that nomodest was active.

Solution

1. In your terminal you type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. You enter your your password
3. You find this line  **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"**
4. You change it this way **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""**
5. You save your file and close it
6. In your terminal you type `sudo update-grub2`
7. You restart

I hope that if someone else has the same problem, it will help you

[the solution comes from here](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/fr-fr/000123893/manual-nomodeset-kernel-boot-line-option-for-linux-booting)